# How to add mac into list in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am referring to a code i copied from this form but i a looking to add/append mac in to a list.

```
mac = '00:00:00:'
for number in range(16**6):
    hex_num = hex(number)[2:].zfill(6)
    print("{}{}{}:{}{}:{}{}".format(mac,*hex_num))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to construct such a list:

```
mac = '00:00:00:'
the_list = ["{}{}{}:{}{}:{}{}".format(mac,*hex(number)[2:].zfill(6))
            for number in range(16**6)]
```

Mind that since 16<sup>6</sup> = 16 777 216, it will take some time to generate the list, and furthermore it will consume a significant amount of memory.